# CSS3 issue with boxes width 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with displaying some boxes CSS3, where the width is set to 100% but doesn't go all the way, i'm sure i made a mistake somewhere but i'm not sure where :).

You'll see in the HTML code and CSS that there are two boxes: "Box" and "Boxgray"

The box div goes all the way to 100% but the boxgray is not...i want the width to be the same for boxgray.

Here is a link with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/gEtp6/2/

Thanks

```
<div class="box" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 5%, #F0F0FF 70%, #E3E7F7 100%);">
        <h1>Download Our Software</h1>

        Download Our Software

    </div>

    <div class="boxgray" style="width:283px; height:180px;">
        <h2><img src="images/windows.png" alt="Download for Windows">
            <a href="Install.exe" onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('download.kit.Windows');" >Windows Installer</a></h2>
        No requirements.
    </div>

    <div class="boxgray" style="width:283px; height:180px;">
        <h2><img src="images/linux.png" alt="Download for Linux">
            <a href="Install.jar" onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('download.kit.Linux');" >Linux</a></h2>
        Java 1.6 or later required.
    </div>

    <div class="boxgray" style="width:283px; height:180px;">
        <h2><img src="images/mac.png" alt="Download for Mac">
            <a href="InstallMac.dmg" onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('download.kit.mac');" >Mac</a></h2>
        <small>On MacOS 10.8 you have to set in System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Allow Applications from Anywhere. We are working to fix this issue.</small>
    </div>

    <div class="box" style="width:100%">
        <h2>Alternative Download</h2>
        For all platforms you can download a <a href="asd.zip" onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('download.kit.zip');" >zip package</a>.
        Java 1.6 or later is required.
        <p>
        In case of problems with the downloaded package or any issue with the software please <a href="support.html">let us know</a>.
        asdasdasdasdasd

        <p>
        <h2>Connect asdasdasd</h2>
        asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
        In this cases please <a href="support.html">write us</a>. 


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to fix the width of the `box` like :

```
.box{
    width: 1024px;
}
```

and normally it works.

Answer (score 0):

but you have given inline style to your `div.boxGray`

```
<div class="boxgray" style="width:283px; height:180px;">
```

either remove the `inline width` or set it to `100%`;

i.e. do this

```
   <div class="boxgray" style="width:100%; height:180px;">
   <!--width changed to 100% -->
```

or this

```
   <div class="boxgray" style="height:180px;"> 
   <!--width removed, as .boxGray class contains 100% width already -->
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/gEtp6/3/)

update:

so  you want to align your  `div.boxGray` in a single row, you can give them, a smaller width, such that, combined width of all the three `.boxGray` should be less than or equal to that of their parent wrapper. 
What? but you don't have a parent wrapper for those small floating divs!! then provide one.

see this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/gEtp6/14/)

Comment: if i'll set it up like that i will have one box 100% width....i want 3 boxes....and to cover the 100% width....any ideas? I've tried to increase the padding also but the last box it jumps underneath the other 2 boxes :(

Comment: what you mean by that, you have 3 divs inside a div? and you want to divide total horizontal width among them? or you simply want divs to have 100% width? in later case, you can have as many 100% width containers as you wish!

Comment: No....what i mean by that...the problem is that my boxes....don't cover the 100% width (all 3 of them must cover the 100%....like 33% for each....look at my first draft: http://jsfiddle.net/gEtp6/2/
The issue is that the 3 boxes(boxgray) don't have the same width as the box above....

Answer (score 0):

> The box div goes all the way to 100% but the boxgray is not...i want
>   the width to be the same for boxgray.

Remove the inline CSS width and the `.boxgray` class will be 100%.

```
 <div class="boxgray" style="width:283px; height:180px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

if you want the two header and footer boxes to be 100% wide, and the three white boxes to be 33% wide each, then you can do like that:

```
div.box {
    width: calc(100% - 32px);
}
div.boxgray {
    width: calc(33.3% - 32px);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LNAhL/2/

**32px are calculated from (5px margin + 10px padding + 1px borders) * 2 sides**

---

A final tought: your `gray-background` divs are called `box`, while your `white-background` divs are called `boxgray`... ?

Comment: nope....the graybackround is boxgray and the white background is just box....once again this solution it messed up the boxes even more :)

Comment: nope... open them with firebug :/// boxgray is white and box is gray. And the solution works fine in Firefox, which browser are you using, ie8 ?

Comment: tested on Chrome, Firefox, IE, the result is the same

Comment: the problem is that my boxes....don't cover the 100% width (all 3 of them must cover the 100%....like 33% for each....look at my first draft: jsfiddle.net/gEtp6/2 The issue is that the 3 boxes(boxgray) don't have the same width as the box above

Comment: then you want 33% width, not 100% width :) updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you set the width of all the boxgray to 283px.
Just remove this and it should be fine !